# Is it possible to reduce the image quality of Motion JPEG file produced using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, video-capture, mjpeg

I am writing a Python script that records video from a usb webcam and stores the resulting file locally on a hard drive. Currently a 60 second file is 27mb.
Format is motion jpeg (MJPG) because the target being observed is in moving water. Moving water confuses video compression algorithms. I'd like to reduce the size of the overall file by lowering the quality of all of the individual JPEG images in the file. Can this be done in OpenCV? Below is what I have so far. Thanks in advance.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import imutils

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if (cap.isOpened() == False): 
  print("Unable to read camera feed")

capture_duration = 60
sleep_duration = 0
frame_width = int('320')
frame_height = int('240')
frame_per_sec = int('1')
 
out = cv2.VideoWriter('C:\\videoPy\\LZ\\outputvideo.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','j','p','g'),frame_per_sec, (frame_width,frame_height))

start_time = time.time()
while( int(time.time() - start_time) < capture_duration ):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=320)
        out.write(frame)
        time.sleep(sleep_duration)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            # Press Q on keyboard to stop recording
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: properties: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga41c5cfa7859ae542b71b1d33bbd4d2b4 (see: quality) alternatively there are ways to pass CLI-like arguments (e.g. bitrate) to the ffmpeg library, if that is being used to write MJPEG (opencv also has a builtin mjpg codec)

Comment: You might try tuning a traditional video codec before you write them off. While I’m sure the default profile may have had terrible results, changing to VBR constant quality and adjusting parameters should be able to improve things considerably.

Comment: What is the framerate of the camera? Setting the VideoWriter to 1fps but feeding it with 30 frames per second will write 1800 frames in 60 seconds (making the video 1800 seconds playback-time). What you want to do is capturing the full framerate but out.write(frame) only on every n-th frame.

Comment: Just use ffmpeg itself for the recording, or any other tool. This does not require programming, nor should it be solved with custom code